# Linux (ubuntu) Permission confusion

Tags: permissions, users, groups

Please, take a look at the following CMD

```
[thunder@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx /]$ id
uid=504(thunder) gid=504(thunder) groups=504(thunder)

[thunder@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx /]$ grep developers /etc/group
developers:x:505:501,502,503,504

[thunder@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx /]$ groups
thunder
```

My question is why doesn't developers show up in my `groups` command

Below you can see

```
[thunder@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx opt]$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root       4096 Mar  7 06:46 aws
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         63 Mar 23 22:37 permissions.sh
drwxrwxr-x 7 root developers 4096 Mar 26 19:30 web
```

The "web" folder has developers as its group,
but still I cannot perform this inside the "web" folder

```
[thunder@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx opt]$ cd web
[thunder@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx web]$ touch a
touch: cannot touch ‘a’: Permission denied
```

Note: I tried logging out and logging back in using the `logout` and `exit` command, but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

`man 5 group` states that the forth section of each line is (emphasis added):

> a list of the **usernames** that are members of this group, separated by commas.

Having numeric user IDs in this list doesn't seem to work.

---

I think you have to use something like

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER developers
```

or

```
sudo usermod $USER -aG developers
```

to actually add yourself to the `developers` group.

After that, logout and re-login, then use

```
id -Gn
```

to get a list of your groups.

Comment: but to run `sudo gpasswd` i will need root access which i don't have

Comment: @ThunderRoid You have to ask the administrator then... because you are not really in developers group.

Comment: but `grep developers /etc/group` shows that i am, because it has my uid, as u can see in op

Comment: There should be a list of the "usernames" not "user id", I tested it on my local machine... uid does not works. I also quoted a line from `/etc/group` manual page:  "

    a list of the usernames that are members of this group, separated by commas."

Comment: I edited your answer to emphasize that one has to put the user names into `/etc/groups`, not the UIDs. At least for me, that wasn't too clear until I saw your comment above. Btw, another (more common?) command to add a USER to a GROUP is `sudo adduser USER GROUP`.

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks so much for clarifying. Btw, `/etc/group` not `/etc/groups`

Comment: Oh, yeah, right. `/etc/group` it is, of course. Happy little typos ;)